# In SwfitUI, having issues with a drag gesture removing the correct grid item. Hoping for a solution

Tags: swift, swiftui, grid, location

I am having issues with this code. Essentially I need an 8x8 grid of squares that can each have their pixel changed to whatever color I need it to be, hence the obnoxious array of colors. There is a mask on top of it of a duplicate grid with black tiles that should disappear a tile at a time as the user drags their finger across. However, it always starts at the top left, no matter where the finger lands. Is there any way to change the code to start the removal of the top tile where the finger initially lands and continues to follow its path?

Thanks!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var bottomGridColors: [[Color]] = [[Color.red, Color.orange, Color.yellow, Color.green, Color.blue, Color.purple, Color.pink, Color.gray],
                                              [Color.red, Color.orange, Color.yellow, Color.green, Color.blue, Color.purple, Color.pink, Color.gray],
                                              [Color.red, Color.orange, Color.yellow, Color.green, Color.blue, Color.purple, Color.pink, Color.gray],
                                              [Color.red, Color.orange, Color.yellow, Color.green, Color.blue, Color.purple, Color.pink, Color.gray],
                                              [Color.red, Color.orange, Color.yellow, Color.green, Color.blue, Color.purple, Color.pink, Color.gray],
                                              [Color.red, Color.orange, Color.yellow, Color.green, Color.blue, Color.purple, Color.pink, Color.gray],
                                              [Color.red, Color.orange, Color.yellow, Color.green, Color.blue, Color.purple, Color.pink, Color.gray],
                                              [Color.red, Color.orange, Color.yellow, Color.green, Color.blue, Color.purple, Color.pink, Color.gray]]
    @State private var topGridRevealed = [[Bool]](repeating: [Bool](repeating: false, count: 8), count: 8)
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(0..<8, id: \.self) { row in
                    HStack(spacing: 0) {
                        ForEach(0..<8, id: \.self) { col in
                            Rectangle()
                                .fill(self.bottomGridColors[row][col])
                                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            VStack(spacing:0) {
                ForEach(0..<8, id: \.self) { row in
                    HStack(spacing: 0) {
                        ForEach(0..<8, id: \.self) { col in
                            Rectangle()
                                .fill(self.topGridRevealed[row][col] ? Color.clear : Color.black)
                                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                                .gesture(
                                    DragGesture()
                                        .onChanged { value in
                                            let x = Int((value.location.x) / 50)
                                            let y = Int((value.location.y) / 50)
                                            if x >= 0 && x < 8 && y >= 0 && y < 8 {
                                                self.topGridRevealed[y][x] = true
                                            }
                                        }
                                )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentViewPreview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Ive tried to use GridReader, but Im not very knowledgeable on SwiftUI, I'm kind of new! Hoping to learn something.!

Answer (score 0):

You have added a separate `DragGesture` to each tile, and each `DragGesture` operates by default in the coordinate space of that tile. So in each `DragGesture`, `(0, 0)` is the top left of that gesture's tile, not the top left of the entire grid.

You only need one `DragGesture` for the whole grid. Move your `.gesture` modifier to the outermost `ZStack`:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        .... blah blah blah...
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(self.topGridRevealed[row][col] ? Color.clear : Color.black)
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                            // REMOVE .gesture from here
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // ADD .gesture here
    .gesture(... blah blah blah ...)
}
```

You might also want to consider a less complicated view structure. Instead of laying out a bunch of `Rectangle`s using stacks, you could draw the entire thing using a single `Canvas`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var revealed = Array(repeating: false, count: widthInCells * heightInCells)

    private static let colors: [Color] = [.red, .orange, .yellow, .green, .blue, .purple, .pink, .gray]
    private static var widthInCells: Int { colors.count }
    private static var heightInCells: Int { 8 }
    private var cellSize: CGFloat { 50 }

    var body: some View {
        Canvas { gc, size in
            for y in 0 ..< Self.heightInCells {
                for x in 0 ..< Self.widthInCells {
                    let path = Path(CGRect(
                        x: CGFloat(x) * cellSize, y: CGFloat(y) * cellSize,
                        width: cellSize, height: cellSize
                    ))
                    let color = revealed[index(x: x, y: y)] ? Self.colors[x] : .black
                    gc.fill(path, with: .color(color))
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(
            width: cellSize * CGFloat(Self.widthInCells),
            height: cellSize * CGFloat(Self.heightInCells)
        )
        .gesture(revealGesture)
    }

    private var revealGesture: some Gesture {
        return DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
            .onChanged { g in
                let x = Int(g.location.x / cellSize)
                let y = Int(g.location.y / cellSize)
                revealed[index(x: x, y: y)] = true
            }
    }

    private func index(x: Int, y: Int) -> Int {
        return max(0, min(y, Self.heightInCells - 1)) * Self.widthInCells + max(0, min(x, Self.widthInCells - 1))
    }
}
```